# Find closest point in Pandas DataFrames

Tags: python, postgresql, pandas

I am quite new to Python. I have the following table in Postgres. These are Polygon values with four coordinates with same `Id` with `ZONE` name I have stored this data in Python dataframe called `df1`

```
Id  Order   Lat              Lon            Zone
00001   1   50.6373473  3.075029928          A
00001   2   50.63740441 3.075068636          A
00001   3   50.63744285 3.074951754          A 
00001   4   50.63737839 3.074913884          A 
00002   1   50.6376054  3.0750528            B
00002   2   50.6375896  3.0751209            B
00002   3   50.6374239  3.0750246            B
00002   4   50.6374404  3.0749554            B
```

I have Json data with `Lon` and `Lat` values and I have stored them is python dataframe called `df2`.

```
Lat                  Lon
50.6375524099   3.07507914474
50.6375714407   3.07508201591
```

My task is to compare `df2` `Lat` and `Lon` values with four coordinates of each zone in `df1` to extract the zone name and add it to `df2`.

For instance `(50.637552409 3.07507914474)` belongs to `Zone B`.

```
#This is ID with Zone
df1 = pd.read_sql_query("""SELECT * from "zmap" """,con=engine)
#This is with lat,lon values
df2 = pd.read_sql_query("""SELECT * from "E1" """,con=engine)
df2['latlon'] = zip(df2.lat, df2.lon)
zones = [
["A", [[50.637347297, 3.075029928], [50.637404408, 3.075068636], [50.637442847, 3.074951754],[50.637378390, 3.074913884]]]]
for i in range(0, len(zones)):  # for each zone points
    X = mplPath.Path(np.array(zones[i][1]))
    # find if points are Zones
    Y= X.contains_points(df2.latlon.values.tolist())
    # Label points that are in the current zone
    df2[Y, 'zone'] = zones[i][0]
```

Currently I have done it manually for Zone 'A'. I need to generate the "Zones" for the coordinates in df2.

Comment: Sorry, SO is not a tutorial or free code writing site. Please show your attempts first.

Comment: It's as simple as `df2.merge(df1)`.

Answer (score 14):

This sounds like a good use case for [scipy cdist](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html), also discussed [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/28207/finding-the-closest-point-to-a-list-of-points).

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist


data1 = {'Lat': pd.Series([50.6373473,50.63740441,50.63744285,50.63737839,50.6376054,50.6375896,50.6374239,50.6374404]),
         'Lon': pd.Series([3.075029928,3.075068636,3.074951754,3.074913884,3.0750528,3.0751209,3.0750246,3.0749554]),
         'Zone': pd.Series(['A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B'])}

data2 = {'Lat': pd.Series([50.6375524099,50.6375714407]),
         'Lon': pd.Series([3.07507914474,3.07508201591])}


def closest_point(point, points):
    """ Find closest point from a list of points. """
    return points[cdist([point], points).argmin()]

def match_value(df, col1, x, col2):
    """ Match value x from col1 row to value in col2. """
    return df[df[col1] == x][col2].values[0]


df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

df1['point'] = [(x, y) for x,y in zip(df1['Lat'], df1['Lon'])]
df2['point'] = [(x, y) for x,y in zip(df2['Lat'], df2['Lon'])]

df2['closest'] = [closest_point(x, list(df1['point'])) for x in df2['point']]
df2['zone'] = [match_value(df1, 'point', x, 'Zone') for x in df2['closest']]

print(df2)
#    Lat        Lon       point                           closest                  zone
# 0  50.637552  3.075079  (50.6375524099, 3.07507914474)  (50.6375896, 3.0751209)  B
# 1  50.637571  3.075082  (50.6375714407, 3.07508201591)  (50.6375896, 3.0751209)  B
```

Comment: Thanks for this excellent answer - it's really helped me :)

Comment: The logic for match_value is very expensive. More efficient to use merge, i.e. df2.merge(df1[['point','zone']].rename(columns={'point':'closest'})

Comment: That is fabulous

Comment: why doesn't anyone get confused by the fact that cdist defaults to a euclidian metric which is not suitable for longitude and width coordinates? And this implementation is extremely inefficient

Answer (score 1):

*note that the current title of the post `Find closest point in Pandas DataFrames` but OP's attempt shows that they are looking for the zone within which a point is found.*

It is possible to leverage the geopandas library to do this operation elegantly & efficiently.

Convert the DataFrame into a GeoDataFrame.

Then aggregate the points in `df1` to create a polygon. The aggregation operation is called `dissolve`.

Finally, use a spatial join `sjoin` with the predicate such that points in df2 are covered by the polygon representing a `Zone` in `zones` and output the `Lat,` Lon`&`Zone` columns.

```py
# set up
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
  'Id': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2],
  'Order': [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4],
  'Lat': [50.6373473, 50.63740441, 50.63744285, 50.63737839, 50.6376054, 50.6375896, 50.6374239, 50.6374404], 
  'Lon': [3.075029928, 3.075068636, 3.074951754, 3.074913884, 3.0750528, 3.0751209, 3.0750246, 3.0749554],
 'Zone': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B']
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
  'Lat': [50.6375524099, 50.6375714407],
  'Lon': [3.07507914474, 3.07508201591] 
})

# convert to GeoDataFrame
df1 = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df1, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df1.Lon, df1.Lat))
df2 = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df2, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df2.Lon, df2.Lat))

# aggregate & merge
zones = df1.dissolve(by='Zone').convex_hull.rename('geometry').reset_index()
merged = df2.sjoin(zones, how='left', predicate='covered_by')

# output
output_columns = ['Lat', 'Lon', 'Zone']
merged[output_columns]
```

this outputs:

```
         Lat       Lon Zone
0  50.637552  3.075079    B
1  50.637571  3.075082    B
```