# How can I speed up closest point comparison using cdist or tensorflow?

Tags: python, performance, pandas, tensorflow

I have two sets of points, one is a map consisting of x,y coordinates, and the second is a path of x,y coordinates. I'm trying to find the closest map points to my path points, pretty simple. Except my map is 380000 points and my paths (of which I have several) each consist of ~ 350000 points themselves.
Other than sampling my data to get smaller datasets, I'm trying to find a faster way to accomplish this task.

## base algorithm:

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
...

def closeset_point(point, points):
    return points[cdist([point], points).argmin()]

# log['point'].shape; 333000
# map_data['point'].shape; 380000
closest = [closest_point(log_p, list(map_data['point'])) for log_p in log['point']]
```

as per this example: [Find closest point in Pandas DataFrames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38965720/find-closest-point-in-pandas-dataframes)

After converting this to a tqdm progress bar to see how long it would take (as it was taking a while, obviously), I noticed it would take about 10hrs to complete.

## tqdm loop:

```
for i in trange(len(log), desc='finding closest points'):
    closest.append(closest_point(log['point'].loc[i], list(map_data['point'])))
>> finding closest points: 5%|   | 16432/333456 [32:11<10:13:52], 8.60it/s
```

While 10 hours is not impossible, I wonder if there is a way to speed this up? I have a solid gpu/cpu/ram at my disposal so I feel this should be doable. I'm also learning tensorflow (but honestly my math is atrocious so I'm very in the dark with it)

Any ideas on how to speed this up with either multi-threading, gpu computation, tensorflow or some other sort of wizardry?
inb4 python is slow ;)

[image: blue is map, green is path, orange is closest point]

*edit: image shows what i'm trying to do. green is path, blue is map, orange is what I'm trying to find.

Comment: So you have a fixed set of map points, and for every path point you want to find the closest map point? You might want to look into some data structures specifically intended for problems like nearest neighbour searches, such as the kd-tree.

Comment: Maybe you could show a few map coordinates, a few path coordinates and a little diagram highlighting what you want to find.

Comment: I managed to shorten it to about 20 minutes. What's fast with cdist is if you do it with two lists, so I batched my path into chunks of 1000 and did cdist(path[x:x+1000], map) and it sped up immensely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following is a mini example of what you're trying to do. Considers the variable `coords1` as your variable `log['point']` and `coords2` as your variable `log['point']`. The end result is the index of the `coord2` closest to `coord1`.

```
from scipy.spatial import distance
import numpy as np
coords1 = [(35.0456, -85.2672),
          (35.1174, -89.9711),
          (35.9728, -83.9422),
          (36.1667, -86.7833)]
coords2 = [(35.0456, -85.2672),
          (35.1174, -89.9711),
          (35.9728, -83.9422),
          (34.9728, -83.9422),
          (36.1667, -86.7833)]


tmp = distance.cdist(coords1, coords2, "sqeuclidean") #  sqeuclidean based on Mark Setchell comment to improve speed further
result = np.argmin(tmp,1)
# result: array([0, 1, 2, 4])
```

This should be way faster, because it's done everything in one iteration.

Comment: I don't speak Python, but can you alter to `distance.cdist(coords1,coords2,'sqeuclidean')` to avoid the square root which is potentially expensive - since if `a^2` < `b^2`, it follows that `a` < `b` (when `a` and `b` are both already squares and therefore positive).

Comment: Nice comment. I'll put it on the answer. Thanks =)

Comment: wow ok, so I figured out to do the list format myself and it went from 10hrs to 20 minutes, and then the 'sqeuclidean' option further reduced it to 12 minutes! thanks!

Answer (score 2):

After 3 years, but if anyone is looking at this issue... You may want to try `Numba` I get almost a 9x speed reduction from `scipy` `distance.cdist` on a 1.5 Million  set of points  to a 1.5 K set of path points. Also,  as @
Mark Setchell said if you want to remove the `np.sqrt` in a big enough set of points could be considerable saved time.

**Results**

```
size: (1459383, 2)
numba:  0.06402060508728027
cdist:  0.5371212959289551
```

**Code**

```
# EUCLEDIAN DISTANCE
@numba.njit('(float64[:,::1], float64[::1], float64[::1])', parallel=True, fastmath=True)
def pz_dist(p_array, x_flat, y_flat):
    m = p_array.shape[0]
    n = x_flat.shape[0]
    d = np.empty(shape=(m, n), dtype=np.float64)
    for i in numba.prange(m):
        p1 = p_array[i, :]
        for j in range(n):
            _x = x_flat[j] - p1[0]
            _y = y_flat[j] - p1[1]
            _d = np.sqrt(_x**2 + _y**2)
            d[i, j] = _d
    return d
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'll definitely check out numba next time I'm working with a lot of data