# Pandas Dataframe: Find the column with the closest coordinate point to another columns coordinate point

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with soccer ball and soccer player tracking data.
I am trying to find the player that is closest to the ball for each row of coordinate points, and make a new column attributing the closest player to the ball

example data

```
| ball_point | home_player1_point | home_player2_point | away_player1_point |
| --------   | --------------     | ----------------------------------
| (7.00,3.00)     (-15.37,8.22)           (25.3,-.2)         (12.0,12.9)
```

desired output

```
| ball_point | home_player1_point | home_player2_point | away_player1_point | closest
| --------   | --------------     | ----------------------------------
| (7.00,3.00)     (-15.37,8.22)           (25.3,-.2)         (7.1,3.2)           away_player1
```

Here is a link to my working notebook : https://github.com/piercepatrick/Articles_EDA/blob/main/nashSCProject.ipynb
The work pertaining to this problem can be found at the bottom, although it is messy right now.
I have also used this question to help me: [Find closest point in Pandas DataFrames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38965720/find-closest-point-in-pandas-dataframes)

Any help appreciated, I need this done by tonight!

Comment: You have a tuple per column. How do you want to identify the closest coordinate point? Is it the sum of the differences across both values?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your dataframe has more rows. First you need to define some functions: a function of distance between two points (I'll use euclidean distance) and a function to get the distance between point in two `pandas.Series` (or dataframe columns):

```
def euc_dist(x,y):
    return ((x[0] - y[0])**2 +(x[1] - y[1])**2 )**(1/2)

def dist(s1,s2):    
    distances = [euc_dist(s1[i],s2[i]) for i in range(s1.shape[0])]
    return pd.Series(distances)
```

The returning value of `dist` has to be a `pandas.Series` because it has to be a new column (I'm assuming your dataframe is called `df`):

```
distances_df = df.iloc[:,1:].apply(dist, args = (df["ball_point"],))
df["closest"] = distances_df.idxmin(axis = 1).apply(lambda x: str(x)[:-6])
```

The function `dist` is applied from the second column onward, that's why I use `df.iloc[:,1:]` and they're allcompared with the "ball_position" column, that's why it is in the `args` parameter, which has to be a `tuple`.

Then you can find the column with the minimum distance using `DataFrame.idxmin`. The lambda function is only to get `"away_player1"` instead of `"away_player1_point"` in the example.

Printing `distances_df` and `df` gives:

```
#distances_df
   home_player1_point  home_player2_point  away_player1_point
0           22.970966           18.577675           11.090987

#df
  ball_point home_player1_point home_player2_point away_player1_point       closest
0     (7, 3)     (-15.37, 8.22)       (25.3, -0.2)       (12.0, 12.9)  away_player1
```

Comment: Thank you so much! In my actual dataframe I have more columns and ball_point isnt in the first column, how should I change the .iloc[:1:] to where it still captures all of the columns? The table can be seen at the very bottom of this notebook: https://github.com/piercepatrick/Articles_EDA/blob/main/nashSCProject.ipynb

Comment: @pmp1321 In that case you have to use df.loc[ : , df.columns != "ball_point"] instead.

Comment: Im getting Key Error: 0

Comment: I put in this line distances_df = tracking_data.loc[ : , tracking_data.columns != "ball_point"].apply(dist, args = (tracking_data["ball_point"],))

Comment: I also just tried plugging in all of my coordinate point columns explicitly (except ball_point) and am getting IndexError: .iloc requires numeric indexers, got [[(-22.06, -8.32) (-0.12, 21.38) (-1.49, -9.62) ... (0.29, 9.88)

Comment: If I use loc and not iloc I get ValueError: Cannot index with multidimensional key

Comment: @pmp1321 if you use the dataframe described in your answer then `df.loc[:, df.columns != "ball_point"]` should work. I tried it.

Comment: @pmp1321 `loc` and `iloc` are for selecting columns and rows. `loc` requires labels and `iloc` requires indices

Comment: I have other columns in my dataframe, not just the coordinate data. Such as time.

Comment: please reference this link of my work: https://github.com/piercepatrick/Articles_EDA/blob/main/nashSCProject.ipynb

Comment: @pmp1321 you can modify your dataframe in order to make the format to match

Comment: @pmp1321 try `df[["col1", "col2"]].apply(tuple, axis = 1)` to "merge" columns into tuples

Comment: distances_df = tracking_data.loc[:,tracking_data[['away_player10_point', 'away_player9_point', 'away_player8_point', 'away_player7_point', 'away_player6_point', 'away_player5_point', 'away_player4_point', 'away_player3_point', 'away_player2_point', 'away_player1_point', 'away_player11_point', 'home_player1_point', 'home_player2_point', 'home_player3_point', 'home_player4_point', 'home_player5_point', 'home_player6_point', 'home_player7_point', 'home_player8_point', 'home_player9_point', 'home_player10_point']].apply(tuple, axis = 1)].apply(dist, args = (tracking_data["ball_point"]))

Comment: This is the line I put in. Is this what you mean. It gets me an error as well

Comment: This is the error. Might be the \n KeyError: "None of [Index([                                                       ((-22.06, -8.32), (-0.12, 21.38), (-1.49, -9.62), (-0.26, -28.52), (-19.32, 16.22), (-15.11, 0.43), (-7.69, 32.87), (0.45, -0.25), (-9.88, 7.67), (-47.29, -0.14), (-18.1, -25.42), (0.46, -19.84), (7.58, 4.82), (15.33, -23.38), (21.08, 6.57), (14.98, 20.7), (8.14, -4.27), (21.36, -9.06), (46.92, 0.01), (0.29, 9.88), (0.67, 22.24), (-0.06, -9.07)),\n                             ((-22.06, -8.32), (-0.07, 21.39), (-1.47, -9.64), (-0.23, -28.51), (-19.31, 16.22)...

Comment: I have posted a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65282498/trying-to-pass-columns-into-function-getting-keyerror-pandas

Comment: Your my best shot at fixing this man, and I need it done for a deadline :(

Comment: @pmp1321 I was about to propose it

Comment: @pmp1321 please consider to mark this one as accepted too