# Trying to pass columns into function, getting keyerror (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I have this code block:

```
def euc_dist(x,y):
    return ((x[0] - y[0])**2 +(x[1] - y[1])**2 )**(1/2)

def dist(s1,s2):    
    distances = [euc_dist(s1[i],s2[i]) for i in range(s1.shape[0])]
    return pd.Series(distances)

distances_df = tracking_data.loc[:,tracking_data[['away_player10_point', 'away_player9_point', 'away_player8_point', 'away_player7_point', 'away_player6_point', 'away_player5_point', 'away_player4_point', 'away_player3_point', 'away_player2_point', 'away_player1_point', 'away_player11_point', 'home_player1_point', 'home_player2_point', 'home_player3_point', 'home_player4_point', 'home_player5_point', 'home_player6_point', 'home_player7_point', 'home_player8_point', 'home_player9_point', 'home_player10_point', 'home_player11_point']].apply(tuple, axis = 1)].apply(dist, args = (tracking_data["ball_point"]))
tracking_data["closest"] = distances_df.idxmin(axis = 1).apply(lambda x: str(x)[:-6])
```

I am getting this error when running:

> KeyError: "None of [Index([
> ((-22.06, -8.32), (-0.12, 21.38), (-1.49, -9.62), (-0.26, -28.52),
> (-19.32, 16.22), (-15.11, 0.43), (-7.69, 32.87), (0.45, -0.25),
> (-9.88, 7.67), (-47.29, -0.14), (-18.1, -25.42), (0.46, -19.84),
> (7.58, 4.82), (15.33, -23.38), (21.08, 6.57), (14.98, 20.7), (8.14,
> -4.27), (21.36, -9.06), (46.92, 0.01), (0.29, 9.88), (0.67, 22.24), (-0.06, -9.07)),\n
> ((-22.06, -8.32), (-0.07, 21.39), (-1.47, -9.64), (-0.23, -28.51),
> (-19.31, 16.22), (-15.1, 0.42), (-7.68, 32.88), (0.46, -0.26), (-9.87,
> 7.7), (-47.3, -0.15), (-18.09, -25.41), (0.43, -19.83), (7.5600000000000005, 4.83), (15.31, -23.38), (21.06, 6.57), (14.97,
> 20.72), (8.12, -4.28), (21.33, -9.04), (46.91, 0.02), (0.25, 9.85), (0.67, 22.24), (-0.11, -9.05)),\n
> ((-22.06, -8.33), (-0.03, 21.39), (-1.43, -9.67), (-0.2, -28.5),
> (-19.29, 16.24), (-15.09, 0.42), (-7.66, 32.9), (0.47000000000000003,
> -0.27), (-9.85, 7.72), (-47.31, -0.16), (-18.08, -25.4), (0.39, -19.83), (7.55, 4.85), (15.28, -23.38), (21.03, 6.57), (14.95, 20.74), (8.09, -4.28), (21.28, -9.02), (46.91, 0.03), (0.2, 9.82), (0.66,
> 22.24), (-0.16, -9.02)),\n                       ((-22.06, -8.34), (0.01, 21.39), (-1.3900000000000001, -9.7), (-0.16, -28.5), (-19.28,
> 16.25), (-15.08, 0.42), (-7.64, 32.92), (0.49, -0.27), (-9.84, 7.75), (-47.32, -0.16), (-18.07, -25.4), (0.3500000000000...

Please reference this notebook to see my table as it is too large to put here. The work pertaining to this question is at the bottom.
https://github.com/piercepatrick/Articles_EDA/blob/main/nashSCProject.ipynb

I have been trying to work out this problem in my previous question: [Pandas Dataframe: Find the column with the closest coordinate point to another columns coordinate point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65272337/pandas-dataframe-find-the-column-with-the-closest-coordinate-point-to-another-c)

I have a hunch that this issue lies in the source data since I originally loaded it in as JSON?

Comment: Your original dataframe columns are like "home_player1_x" and "home_player1_y", why are you using "home_player1_point"?

Comment: Not sure, thought I needed to for the euclidean distance formula.

Comment: Plus its half of the columns to pass into the function.

Comment: it was correct, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, reset the index with

```
tracking_data = tracking_data.reset_index()
```

Then change

```
distances_df = tracking_data.loc[:,tracking_data[['away_player10_point', 'away_player9_point', 'away_player8_point', 'away_player7_point', 'away_player6_point', 'away_player5_point', 'away_player4_point', 'away_player3_point', 'away_player2_point', 'away_player1_point', 'away_player11_point', 'home_player1_point', 'home_player2_point', 'home_player3_point', 'home_player4_point', 'home_player5_point', 'home_player6_point', 'home_player7_point', 'home_player8_point', 'home_player9_point', 'home_player10_point', 'home_player11_point']].apply(tuple, axis = 1)].apply(dist, args = (tracking_data["ball_point"]))
```

for

```
distances_df = tracking_data[['away_player10_point', 'away_player9_point', 'away_player8_point', 'away_player7_point', 'away_player6_point', 'away_player5_point', 'away_player4_point', 'away_player3_point', 'away_player2_point', 'away_player1_point', 'away_player11_point', 'home_player1_point', 'home_player2_point', 'home_player3_point', 'home_player4_point', 'home_player5_point', 'home_player6_point', 'home_player7_point', 'home_player8_point', 'home_player9_point', 'home_player10_point', 'home_player11_point']].apply(dist, args = (tracking_data["ball_point"],))
```

Comment: ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().                                                                                                                         Looking into it, might be able to fix myself. Ive seen this error before.

Comment: KeyError:0                                                                                                                                  If you go onto github, you should be able to download the notebook so you can test things, that may be easier?

Comment: @pmp1321 I can't load the json file

Comment: @pmp1321 does `tracking_data[['away_player10_point', 'away_player9_point', 'away_player8_point', 'away_player7_point', 'away_player6_point', 'away_player5_point', 'away_player4_point', 'away_player3_point', 'away_player2_point', 'away_player1_point', 'away_player11_point', 'home_player1_point', 'home_player2_point', 'home_player3_point', 'home_player4_point', 'home_player5_point', 'home_player6_point', 'home_player7_point', 'home_player8_point', 'home_player9_point', 'home_player10_point', 'home_player11_point']]` return something?

Comment: Yes, that command displays the dataframe with those columns

Comment: are you sure you're writting exaclty `.apply(dist, args = (tracking_data["ball_point"],))` after that?

Comment: Unless you have anymore ideas, I think im going to give up. I appreciate your help man.

Comment: @pmp1321 did you check my update? the `reset_index` thing

Comment: No where did you send that? Never mind trying now

Comment: @pmp1321 I edited this post, it worked for me

Comment: IT WORKS! THank you!

Comment: @pmp1321 nice! :D

Comment: @pmp1321 please mark it as accepted and consider voting it