# Finding closest point from a dataframe without repetition

Tags: python, pandas, loops, points, closest-points

I have two dataframes `df1` and `df2`.

I want to find the closest point from `df2` corresponding to the points in the `df1`.
Once a point is selected from `df2` corresponding to the point in `df1`, remove it from `df2` dataframe (To avoid the repetition of points in `df1`) and move to the next point in `df1`.

df1

```
        X     Y
0    74.7  30.7
1    74.9  30.7
2    75.1  30.7
3    75.3  30.7
4    75.5  30.7
```

df2

```
      X     Y
0   75.80  33.00
1   75.80  33.00
2   76.40  33.00
3   75.80  33.00
4   76.38  33.00
5   76.45  33.00
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38965720/find-closest-point-in-pandas-dataframes) answer is pretty close but to avoid the chances of duplicate values, How to return the index of the closest point along with the point itself?

My code

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

def closest_point(point, points):
    """ Find closest point from a list of points. """
    return cdist([point], points).argmin(), points[cdist([point], points).argmin()]

dff1=pd.DataFrame() 
dff2=pd.DataFrame()
dff1['point'] = [(x, y) for x,y in zip(df1['Y'], df1['X'])]
dff2['point'] = [(x, y) for x,y in zip(df2['Y'], df2['X'])]

P=[]
for x in dff1['point']:
    idx,p=closest_point(x, list(dff2['point']))
    P.append(p)
    dff2.drop(idx,inplace=True)
```

But somehow this is not working

How to solve this ? please suggest some solutions.

Comment: Are you finding the closest point in df2 for each point in df1? If so how would you do when a point in df2 is the closest for multiple points in df1?

Comment: What I had in mind was, once we assign the closest point from df2 to a point in df1, removing it from from df2 solve this confusion. So the other points would find some alternate closest point.